# Use a column in the jointable on the where

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've 3 tables on this piece of code, the tables are :

Users - With information about the users
Widgets - With information about the widgets
user_widgets - use for the m-n relationship between the previous tables

The last table, other than the ids of the other 2 tables have 2 extra fields : read and write

The code i've used to connect to these tables are

```
 Widget.belongsToMany(User, { through:User_widget, foreignKey: 'widget_id' });
 User.belongsToMany(Widget, { through:User_widget, foreignKey: 'user_id' });
```

The User_widget has an alias as "perms", so when i call

```
User.findOne ... then(function(user){
   user.getWidgets().then(function(widgets) {
```

In the widgets object returned I have the perms object with the 2 fields read and write, so all works fine.

My problem is I need to filter the Widgets so that i get only the widgets in which I have read perms.

I've tried with

```
user.getWidgets({
   where : {
      read : false
   }})
```

but it produces a sql query like

```
SELECT "widget"."id", "widget"."name", "perms"."widget_id" AS "perms.widget_id", "perms"."user_id" AS "perms.user_id", "perms"."read" AS "perms.read", "perms"."write" AS "perms.write" 
FROM "widgets" AS "widget" 
WHERE "widget"."read" = false 
INNER JOIN "user_widget" AS "perms" ON "widget"."id" = "perms"."widget_id" AND "perms"."user_id" = '5';
```

I need a query like this :

```
SELECT "widget"."id", "widget"."name", "perms"."widget_id" AS "perms.widget_id", "perms"."user_id" AS "perms.user_id", "perms"."read" AS "perms.read", "perms"."write" AS "perms.write" 
FROM "widgets" AS "widget" 
INNER JOIN "user_widget" AS "perms" ON "widget"."id" = "perms"."widget_id" AND "perms"."user_id" = '5' AND "perms"."read" = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
user.getWidgets({
  through: {
    where : {
      read : false
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I've already tried, it produce me this query, the through is completely ignored 

`SELECT "widget"."id", "widget"."name", "perms"."widget_id" AS "perms.widget_id", "perms"."user_id" AS "perms.user_id", "perms"."read" AS "perms.read", "perms"."write" AS "perms.write" FROM "widgets" AS "widget" INNER JOIN "user_widget" AS "perms" ON "widget"."id" = "perms"."widget_id" AND "perms"."user_id" = '5';`

Comment: Your code don't works, cause in the code of sequelize that functionality don't exists, so i've modified the code to make work

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/4739